# Neo4j make unique relation with a new node

Tags: neo4j

I want to get the realtion a_number called b_number

but the duplicate values should be deleated
example 07122  ---> called  07133
           07133 ----> called 07122

it should only have 07122 ---> called 07133

and the other thing is only starting with "071"______  are taken all the other numbers are not taken eg:- "077" , "072", "022"

Note the a_number  contain only numbers that are starting with "071"
but the b_number has various different numbers and "071" too

[excell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uwmo.png)

[Neo4j](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qxGe.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clause can create an [undirected relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-on-an-undirected-relationship).

Here is a sample snippet (I assume that the Cypher code before the snippet gets the desired `a_number` and `b_number` nodes):

```
MERGE (a_number)-[:CALLED]-(b_number)
```

The snippet will only create a new `CALLED` relationship between those 2 nodes if an existing relationship does not already exist in either direction